# Deformation quantization of a closed Riemann surface with genus >1

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, noncommutative-geometry, quantization

Quantization of of an elliptic curve can be done in different ways.
In `C^*`-algebraic version,
one can start with the `C^*`-algebra of continuous functions on ordinary torus and by inserting a deformation parameter `\theta` into the product obtain a deformed non-commutaive `C^*`-algebra of functions on the quantum torus.

My question is:

Is there any natural way for deformation quantization of closed Riemann surfaces with higher genus in the above sense?

Answer (score 4):

One should definitely take a look at the work of Bordemann, Meinrenken, and Schlichenmaier: they provide a Berezin-Toeplitz inspired deformation quantization for all compact quantizable (i.e. the Kähler form is integral) Kähler manifolds. The asymptotics of this was discussed before by Cahen, Gutt, and Rawnsley in their 4 papers of quantization on Kähler manifolds. Later, Schlichenmaier and Karabegov determined the characteristic classes of the resulting formal star products explicitly, relating the BT-approach also to other versions.

Answer (score 3):

See the paper *Quantization of Multiply Connected Manifolds*, by Eli Hawkins.  [arXiv link](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0304246).